# Can't display a satellite TIFF image in Spyder using Python

Tags: python, gdal, image

I wish to create a Python script that opens a multiband satellite tiff image, then selects the bands the RGB image will be displayed with and then from this point and then I can collect my data from the image. However, I keep getting this error: "`TypeError: Invalid shape (3, 1301, 1950) for image data`". Note that this error doesn't appear when it is a single band image and the image displays without any problem. What's the matter with my code?

```
import gdal
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Open the Sentinel-2 image using GDAL
sentinel_ds = gdal.Open(r'C:\Users\GNR\Desktop\file_example_TIFF_10MB (2).tiff')

# Get the band count and band descriptions
band_count = sentinel_ds.RasterCount
band_descriptions = [sentinel_ds.GetRasterBand(i+1).GetDescription() for i in range(band_count)]

# Print the band count and descriptions
print(f'The image has {band_count} bands:')
for i, desc in enumerate(band_descriptions):
    print(f'Band {i+1}: {desc}')

# Select the Red, Green, and Blue bands (bands 4, 3, and 2)
red_band = sentinel_ds.GetRasterBand(4).ReadAsArray()
green_band = sentinel_ds.GetRasterBand(3).ReadAsArray()
blue_band = sentinel_ds.GetRasterBand(2).ReadAsArray()

# Create an RGB image from the bands
rgb_image = plt.imshow([red_band, green_band, blue_band])

# Display the RGB image
plt.show()
```

Comment: Which line throws the error?

Comment: The one I am trying to display the image with, : rgb_image = plt.imshow([red_band, green_band, blue_band]).

Answer (score 4):

You need to reshape the list as ( width, height, z (bands) ). Currently, it is (bands, width, height). That's why you're getting the error.

```
import numpy as np

...

bands = np.array([red_band, green_band, blue_band]).transpose(1, 2, 0)

rgb_image = plt.imshow(bands)

plt.show()
```